# Attach hover tooltip to specific div from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a tooltip (div) to display with information via AJAX. Here is the function that will do it:

```
function coworkerDetail(post, delay) {
    if(delay == 1) {
        clearInterval(TipTimer);
    } else {
        TipTimer = setInterval(function(){

            var msgType = 'person-container';
            // The position to be increased
            var height = 58;
            var left = 20;

        // Start displaying the profile card with the preloader
        $('.coworker-detail').show();
        $('.coworker-detail').html('<div class="loading"><div class="loading-dot"></div><div class="loading-dot"></div><div class="loading-dot"></div><div class="loading-dot"></div></div>');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.coworker-detail').html('Info goes here');
            }
        });
        clearInterval(TipTimer);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

However, I need the tooltip to display only for the specific person-container div that I hover over in the loop:

```
$.each(obj.DATA, function( indexInArray, value ) {

    var topConnectedHtml = '<div class="person-container">' + 
    '<div class="headshot">' +
        '<div class="initials">' + firstinitial + lastinitial + 
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="hover-wrapper" onmouseover="coworkerDetail(1, 0)" onmouseout="coworkerDetail(0, 1);" onclick="coworkerDetail(0, 1);">' + 
        '<div class="name">' + value[firstNameIndex] + ' ' + value[lastNameIndex] + '</div>' +
        '<div class="title">' + value[titleIndex] + '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="coworker-detail">' +
    '</div>' +
```

Currently, when I hover over ANY person-container, it is bringing back EVERY tooltip for all person-containers. **I need to select the specific one it's hovering over.**

Answer (score 0):

If your .hover-wrapper always accompanies the detail div, you could pass a reference like:

```
 onmouseover="coworkerDetail(this, 1, 0)"
```

Then change your coworkerDetail function to be:

```
function coworkerDetail(el, post, delay) {
```

Then instead of using:

```
$('.coworker-detail')
```

get

```
var detail = $(el).siblings('.coworker-detail').first();
```

and use that instead. This finds the one .coworker-detail div assocuated with the hover element.

Comment: Good, but perhaps tell OP why his initial code didn't work as expected; and better would be attaching it to all coworker details with `$('.coworker-details').on('mouseover', function() { $(this).... //do stuff`.

Comment: When I implemented this, I get nothing back at all.

Comment: When I did a console.log("test",detail), here's what came back: [prevObject: e.fn.init[0], context: undefined, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are saying about the console.log, but I did notice one error in the answer that I fixed, and I created an example Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/ycc16q99/.

Answer (score -1):

Add an id property on the hovered object.

```
<div id="'+id+'" class=".hoverClass">
```

Then you'll be able to request this id inside hover event

```
$('.hoverClass').hover(function(){
    var idHovered = $(this).attr('id');
    //do your post here with specified id
    //then you can output data within the correct object id
});
```

Comment: By far the most inefficient way to accomplish what OP wants (requiring an ID for every class).